# How to check what was the previous tag and why it has been removed?

Tags: support

I am sure that back in the day I added tags to the following questions:

https://devops.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/untagged

It looks like that these have been removed as they have only the [untagged](https://devops.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/untagged) tag.

Comment: [What causes a question to be tagged as "untagged"?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/167879/what-causes-a-question-to-be-tagged-as-untagged)

Comment: @Tensibai is it possible to get a list of these removed tags or should I just check for untagged question so now and then. While typing I think I should do this.

Comment: That's it I think, I'll ask other mods if some have an idea out of browsing the question in archive.org :)